# Make UIWebView Like New On Each App Startup

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, browser-cache

Simple question that would be fantastic if somebody could answer.

I have a simple UIWebView used to log in to a certain service. However, when I reload the application, it stays logged in. What I need to be able to do is create the UIWebView like new each and every time the application starts. I'm not sure if there is an option somewhere in the interface builder, or perhaps a method of some kind I can place in the method that gets called when the app terminates, so that it releases the WebView or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is not save the cache of the UIwebView. You can do this with a simple code like:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Place the code in the UIwebview code.

Or in ApplicationDidFinishLoad (or something like that, haha) you can remove the cache with:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

**Edit:**

You've asked something in the comments. You can do something like the code below:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 20.f)];
        [webView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];

//No Cache\\

      NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
        [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

//No Cache\\

        webView.delegate = self;
        [webView loadRequest:request];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Ok,

Remove a specific request

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:NSURLRequest];
```

Or delete al cookies from the UIWebView

```
for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

    if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:someNSStringUrlDomain]) {

        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Good luck,
Nathan

Comment: I just have one question. You said "place in the webview code", but where are you talking about specifically? Ex. viewDidLoad

Comment: I tried it, however is still seems to retain the information. I've placed it in the "viewDidLoad" method. I'm not quite sure how it's still retaining information..

Comment: Please post your code in the your first message i will take a look. :)

Comment: You can find the code here: http://pastebin.com/eFwWjqqP

Again, it's in the viewDidLoad. I did nothing with your cache code other than putting it physically in the viewDidLoad, I don't know if I was supposed to link it to something. Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: i said 'OR'!!! Remove your last line: [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

Comment: I took it out. Still continues to be logged in on any service that I log into, even after quitting the app. There has to be a way to release the web view or destroy the cache so that it's like a new webview each and every time?

Comment: Edited my message again let me know

Comment: You're great, really. Thanks for doing extra. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project! :)

Answer (score 1):

My answer will be in multiple parts to cover multiple bases.

1 - it's possible the app has a cookie set for the user so even when launching a new app the old cookie remains with the login details and therefore you will still be logged in.

To kill the cookies, try this before the uiwebview loads (ie in the viewwillload or other method)

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
   [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

2 - Is this on a multithreaded phone (iOS4 or newer on a 3GS or newer)? Are you sure the app is terminating as opposed to just going to background? If this is the case and you are just launching the previous app (where you were still logged in) you will need to hook into the - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application and remove the old web view and add a new one.